# Disable website's caching when it's converted to AMP format

Tags: html, caching, amp-html

I recently converted my website to AMP. 
It turned out, that there are some validation errors like e.g.

```
The attribute 'http-equiv' may not appear in tag 'meta name= and content='
```

This error message is related to the description of my page's caching.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Do you know if there is available a clean solution or at least a workaround to fix it?

Comment: Configure your server to send the real HTTP response headers, instead of using the http-equiv “fallback.”